# How can I change the tags in the context menu?

Tags: finder, shortcut-menu, finder-tag

I can't find any way to edit the tags within the context menu which appears when you double-tap on a file in Finder. Is there a way to choose which ones appear? An example of what I mean is below:

[image: Screenshot of the context menu tags]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Finder prefs [Finder menu > Preferences... or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>,</kbd>  > Tags

You can check which to show in the sidebar in the top section & in the lower section you can drag & drop the set to use on contextual menus.  It will replace the tag you drag to with the new one.

[image]